# Create new objects in for loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I have a page that displays graphs based on the selected criteria. Each graph is a separate instance and needs its own object reference. I have new objects being created within the for loop but how can I access those objects outside that particular function.

```
var chartObject = new Array();

function runInit () {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() { 
        $("#pointList :selected").each(function(){
            selectedValues.push($(this).val()); 
        });

        for(var j = 0; j < selectedValues.length; j++)
        {
            chartObject[j] = new Object();

            var charts = [];

            charts.push( drawDataView( demos[demo] ) );

            chartObject[j].allDataLoaded = function( ) {
                //more code             
            };
        }
    }); 
});
}
```

I need to use `chartObject[j]` in another function:

```
function drawDataView ( demo ) {
    var dataCache = new DataCache( chartObject[j], dataSource );
}
```

Obviously `j` isn't defined in `drawDataView`, so how can I create new objects within that for-loop and use the variable elsewhere?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass `j` as an extra parameter to the `drawDataView` function:

```
function drawDataView(demo, j) {
    var dataCache = new DataCache( chartObject[j], dataSource );
}
```

and call it like this:

```
charts.push(drawDataView(demos[demo], j));
```

**Update**

Because you're not returning anything in the `drawDataView` function, your array will be filled with `undefined`. I think you want to add `return dataCache;` at the end.

Comment: I'm an idiot, thank you! Another quick question, am I creating the objects properly? Just wanted to make sure since I'm not getting the results I wanted

Comment: You're welcome. I added an update which I think will explain your unexpected results.